# GConf gconftool - spawn doesn't work

Tags: ubuntu, administration, gconf

Last time I started to having problem with gconftools, I'm using Ubuntu Server Edition 10.04 LTS

When I make command

> gconftools-2 --spawn

I've gor an error:

> Failed to spawn the configuration
>   server (gconfd): Failed to contact
>   configuration server; some possible
>   causes are that you need to enable
>   TCP/IP networking for ORBit, or you
>   have stale NFS locks due to a system
>   crash. See
>   http://projects.gnome.org/gconf/ for
>   information. (Details -  1: Not
>   running within active session)

I deleted .gconf and tried again but it didn't work. Then I apt-get purge gconf2 gconf2-common
 and apt-get install gconf2 gconf2-common but that didn't help either.
Any one get idea what is make gconf to falling?

Thanks for any help.

With regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you have no dbus session running; try this:

```
# dbus-launch bash
# gconftool-2 --ping ; echo $?
2
# gconftool-2 --spawn
# gconftool-2 --ping ; echo $?
0
```